# Where are my kernels?

Tags: command-line, kernel, uninstall

When I type

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
$
```

I just do not get anything back.

So, I cannot uninstall my old kernels.

If type `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux`:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep linux
libselinux1:amd64               install
libselinux1:i386                install
linux-firmware                  install
linux-headers-3.16.0-30             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-41             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-41-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-43             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-43-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-44             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-44-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-45             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-45-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-46             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-46-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-48             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-48-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-49             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-49-generic         install
linux-headers-3.16.0-50             install
linux-headers-3.16.0-50-generic         install
linux-libc-dev:amd64                install
linux-sound-base                install
pptp-linux                  install
syslinux                    install
syslinux-common                 install
syslinux-legacy                 install
util-linux                  install
```

UPDATE:
I do not know if is it important, but this is the way that I use to install new kernels:

```
sudo make menuconfig
sudo make
sudo make modules
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

SOLUTION:

Now I understand the difference between an updated kernel and install and compile a kernel. I compiled all this kernel and the solution to delete was:

I went to nautilus as root `sudo nautilus` and just deleted:

/boot/vmlinuz "kernel I want to delete"

/boot/initrd "kernel I want to delete"

/boot/System "kernel I want to delete"

/boot/config "kernel I want to delete"

/lib/modules "kernel I want to delete"

and updated the grub `sudo update-grub2`

thank everyone!

Comment: What about just `dpkg --get-selections`, and `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux`?

Comment: Just do `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` and it should automatically uninstall your old kernels.

Comment: I type: `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`

And something was deleted, but I switch off/on my computer and old kernel still there (in the grub).

The grub show me 4.1.6 - 4.2.0 and 4.2.5.

Comment: If you manually compiled and installed your own kernel from source then dpkg does not know anything about it and you have to delete them manually.

Comment: @psusi mm... yes, I compiled and installed the kernel. is there a easy way to delete manually?

Comment: If you still have the source, I think a `sudo make uninstall` will delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you compiled your kernel from source, so dpkg won't give you any output. If you still have the source from where the kernel was compiled, open a terminal, run 'cd /path/to/source' and then 'sudo make uninstall' (do NOT do this if it is your current kernel).

Comment: If you mean the kernel folder that I used to compile the kernel... no, I do not have it. is it that the only way to delete? I find some information that could solve this, about how to delete custom kernel. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` that does the trick for me. To get the current kernel that is in use you can run `uname -r`.
**MAKE SURE NOT TO REMOVE THE CURRENT RUNNING KERNEL**

To remove a kernel you can use `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic` of course replace `3.13.0-66` with the version you want to remove.
You can remove multiple kernels with a command like `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-{66,67}-generic` (just replace `66,67` with the versions you want to remove)

The `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` will show you two version for each kernel, for example `linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic` and `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic` you can just ignore the second one (the one with `-extra`) as it will get removed by the `apt-get purge` command.

Example for me:

```
pascal@Lenovo-2013:~$ uname -r
3.13.0-68-generic
pascal@Lenovo-2013:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic                         3.13.0-66.108                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic                         3.13.0-67.110                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic                         3.13.0-68.111                                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic                   3.13.0-66.108                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic                   3.13.0-67.110                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic                   3.13.0-68.111                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.68.74                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
pascal@Lenovo-2013:~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-{66,67}-generic
[sudo] password for pascal:
```

After that it will ask your confirmation for the uninstal.

Comment: Same as `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image` nothing happen. `stefano@giatti-sala:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
stefano@giatti-sala:~$ uname -r
4.2.5
stefano@giatti-sala:~$ `

Comment: @StefanoFoggetti does that mean if you type `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` there is no output?

Comment: That is right. there is no output. not even show me my current kernel.

Comment: @StefanoFoggetti what about `dpkg -l`? that should output a huge list. If that's so, could you try to use `dpkg -l | grep kernel` for me that doesn't only display the kernels but for example `libdrm-intel1:amd64 [...] Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime` too. If you find the your kernels in there you can look for a keyword to use in `dpkg -l | grep keyword`

Comment: I see a lot of information about kernel, but there is only information about old kernel headers 3.x that do not appear in my grub, nothing about my previous kernels images 4.1.6 and 4.2 that still there in my grub.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that extends my knowledge :( good luck!

Comment: @StefanoFoggetti di niente